# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity (When the sharing window is canceled)

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, resume

When the sharing window is canceled
The program stops.
When sharing, the text sharing window will appear and the text will be shared.

But when the sharing window is shown
Touching the back button will make an error and exit the application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZWlz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvIho.jpg)

**Logcat**

```
01-18 16:18:25.177 166-514/? E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (No such file or directory)

    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
01-18 16:18:25.487 3157-3157/ir.hetbo.book_java E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setEnterSharedElementCallback
01-18 16:18:25.497 3157-3157/ir.hetbo.book_java E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback
01-18 16:18:26.807 3157-3157/ir.hetbo.book_java E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.hetbo.book_java, PID: 3157
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ir.hetbo.book_java/ir.hetbo.book_java.main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2786)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at ir.hetbo.book_java.main$1.onTabSelected(main.java:142)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(BottomBar.java:481)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(BottomBar.java:465)
        at ir.hetbo.book_java.main.bottomtabs(main.java:137)
        at ir.hetbo.book_java.main.onResume(main.java:87)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1209)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-18 16:18:35.967 3205-3205/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-18 16:18:35.967 3205-3205/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

main.java

```
package ir.hetbo.book_java;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;
import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBarTab;
import com.roughike.bottombar.OnTabSelectListener;

import java.io.IOException;

import ir.hetbo.book_java.database.DBOpenHelper;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.fragments.Contact;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.fragments.Favorite;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.fragments.Category;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.fragments.Recent;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.fragments.Setting;

public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sp;
    BottomBar bar;
    FrameLayout frame;

    Category Category;
    Contact contact;
    Favorite favorite;
    Recent recent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final boolean useDarkTheme = sp.getBoolean("dark2",false);
        if (useDarkTheme)
            setTheme(R.style.dark);
        else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            SetColorPrimary();
        }

        SetColorAccent();

        boolean screen = sp.getBoolean("screen",false);
        if (screen)
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        else {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        //getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent2));
        //getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent2));
        //}

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //overridePendingTransition( R.anim.fadeout,R.anim.fadein);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);
        bar = findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);

        bottomtabs(bar);

        DBOpenHelper helper = new DBOpenHelper(this);
        try {
            helper.importDB();
        }catch (IOException e){

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bottomtabs(bar);
    }


    private void bottomtabs(BottomBar bar){
        //انتخاب رنگ باتن بار در صورتی که تم مشکلی باشد یا نباشد
        boolean useDarkTheme = sp.getBoolean("dark2",false);
        if (useDarkTheme){
            //رنگ باتن بار مشکی میشود
            BottomBarTab tab1 = bar.getTabAtPosition(0);
            tab1.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
            BottomBarTab tab2 = bar.getTabAtPosition(1);
            tab2.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
            BottomBarTab tab3 = bar.getTabAtPosition(2);
            tab3.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
            BottomBarTab tab4 = bar.getTabAtPosition(3);
            tab4.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
            BottomBarTab tab5 = bar.getTabAtPosition(4);
            tab5.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#212121"));
        }
        else {
            // رنگ باتن بار برای هر تب یک رنگ Set میشود
            BottomBarTab tab1 = bar.getTabAtPosition(0);
            tab1.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#E91E63"));
            BottomBarTab tab2 = bar.getTabAtPosition(1);
            tab2.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#FF9800"));
            BottomBarTab tab3 = bar.getTabAtPosition(2);
            tab3.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
            BottomBarTab tab4 = bar.getTabAtPosition(3);
            tab4.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#009688"));
            BottomBarTab tab5 = bar.getTabAtPosition(4);
            tab5.setBarColorWhenSelected(Color.parseColor("#9c27b0"));
        }

        // ماندن در صفحه تنظیمات در صورتی که برنامه ریست شود.
        final boolean settingapp = sp.getBoolean("Setting",false);
        if (settingapp) {
            bar.selectTabAtPosition(3);
            sp.edit().putBoolean("Setting", false).apply();
        }

        //انتخاب تب پیش فرض

        boolean selectTab = sp.getBoolean("selectTab",true);
        if (selectTab) {
            bar.selectTabAtPosition(2);//انتخاب تب
            sp.edit().putBoolean("selectTab", false).apply();
        }
        bar.setAnimation(null);

        bar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {
                switch (tabId) {
                    case R.id.tab_recent:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,new Recent()).commit();                       break;
                    case R.id.tab_favorite:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,new Favorite()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_list:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,new Category()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_setting:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,new Setting()).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_contact:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,new Contact()).commit();
                        break;
                }
            }});
    }
    private  void SetColorPrimary(){
        String ColorPrimary = sp.getString("ColorPrimary","md_orange_500");
        switch(ColorPrimary){
            case "md_red_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary__md_red_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_pink_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_pink_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_purple_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_purple_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_deep_purple_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_deep_purple_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_indigo_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_indigo_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_blue_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_blue_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_light_blue_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_light_blue_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_cyan_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_cyan_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_teal_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_teal_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_green_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_green_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_light_green_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_light_green_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_lime_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_lime_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_yellow_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_yellow_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_amber_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_amber_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_orange_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_orange_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_deep_orange_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_deep_orange_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_brown_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_brown_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_grey_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_grey_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_blue_grey_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_blue_grey_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_white":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorPrimary_md_white, true);
                break;
        }

    }
    private  void SetColorAccent(){
        String colorAccent = sp.getString("colorAccent","md_orange_500");
        switch(colorAccent){
            case "md_red_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_red_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_pink_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_pink_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_purple_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_purple_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_deep_purple_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_deep_purple_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_indigo_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_indigo_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_blue_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_blue_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_light_blue_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_light_blue_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_cyan_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_cyan_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_teal_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_teal_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_green_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_green_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_light_green_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_light_green_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_lime_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_lime_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_yellow_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_yellow_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_amber_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_amber_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_orange_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_orange_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_deep_orange_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_deep_orange_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_brown_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_brown_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_grey_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_grey_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_blue_grey_500":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_blue_grey_500, true);
                break;
            case "md_white":
                getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayColorAccent_md_white, true);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Recent.java

```
package ir.hetbo.book_java.fragments;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import ir.hetbo.book_java.R;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.StoryClass;
import ir.hetbo.book_java.database.DBOpenHelper;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Recent extends Fragment {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    int id;
    AppCompatTextView category;
    AppCompatTextView title;
    AppCompatTextView story;
    AppCompatImageView star;
    AppCompatImageView share;
    LinearLayout bar;
    AppCompatTextView nr;

    View v;
    public Recent() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent, container, false);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        category = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dast);
        title = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);
        story = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.story);

        star = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.star);
        share = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.share);

        bar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bar);
        nr = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.norecent);preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = preferences.getInt("RecentID",0);



        if (id == 0){
            nr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        }

        final StoryClass sc = new StoryClass(0,"",0,0,"");

        final DBOpenHelper helper = new DBOpenHelper(getContext());

        helper.open();

        Cursor c = helper.getStroy(id);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            int sId = c.getInt(0);
            String stitle = c.getString(1);
            int scategory = c.getInt(2);
            int sFav = c.getInt(3);
            String sStory = c.getString(4);
            category.setText(String.valueOf(scategory));
            title.setText(stitle);
            story.setText(sStory);

            star.setImageResource(sFav == 1 ? R.drawable.star2 : R.drawable.star_outline2);

            sc.setId(sId);
            sc.setFavorite(sFav);
            sc.setStory(sStory);
            sc.setCategory(scategory);
            sc.setTitle(stitle);
        }


        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sc.getStory());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"اشتراک گذاری با..."));
            }
        });


        star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                helper.open();
                star.setImageResource(sc.getFavorite() == 0 ? R.drawable.star2 : R.drawable.star_outline2);
                helper.setFav(id,sc.getFavorite() == 1 ? 0 : 1);
                helper.close();
                sc.setFavorite(sc.getFavorite()== 1 ? 0 : 1);
                helper.close();
            }
        });

        int f = preferences.getInt("font",1);
        int s = preferences.getInt("size",15);

        title.setTextSize(s+5);
        story.setTextSize(s);
        category.setTextSize(15);

        Typeface t1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "homa.ttf");
        Typeface t2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "koodak.ttf");
        Typeface t3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "nazanin.ttf");
        Typeface t4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "titr.ttf");
        Typeface t5 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "iransans.ttf");
        Typeface[] t = {t1,t2,t3,t4,t5};
        title.setTypeface(t[f-1]);
        story.setTypeface(t[f-1]);
        category.setTypeface(t[f-1]);

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.hetbo.book_java">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/dark">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".ReadStory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```